# How does a "for each" loop in C++ know the length of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I was looking at the following example from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/ and I couldn't figure out how the 2nd for loop worked. How can the for loop know when the array ends. If it can figure this out why does the first loop not use a similar approach? It was my impression that the length of an array could not be determined. I'm not sure how to reconcile these notions. Thanks!

**Edit: Thanks for all the great answers!**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int myarray[3] = {10,20,30};

  for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    ++myarray[i];

  for (int elem : myarray)
    cout << elem << '\n';
}
```

Comment: It uses `std::end`, which takes the array and can use the size because the size is part of the type.

Comment: The compiler knows the length of an array.

Comment: The array has size information in its type. This is used in the range based loop. See for example how the length is obtained in [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end).

Comment: Note that in this regard, there is a big difference between proper arrays (type `T[N]` for some `T` and `N`) and pointers (which are often confused with, and considered nigh-identical with, "arrays").

Comment: It's syntactic sugar, it actually uses `std::begin()` and `std::end()`.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: @delnan: You might want to point out what the actual difference is, then (Range-based for loops require proper arrays, a pointer won't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're under a misconception that a ranged-for needs to know the number of iterations (the "length") in advance.  It does not.

It does need a termination condition, which has the form `it != __end` where `__end = x.end()` or `__end = end(x)`.

Of course, arrays can't change their size, so in this one case detecting the end and knowing the length are equivalent (length can be gotten from begin, end, and pointer subtraction).

As Oli mentioned in the comments, the type of an array does contain length information, and `std::end` uses an array reference for its parameter, to avoid the decay to pointer which loses this information.

The definition is basically:

```
namespace std
{
    template<typename T, size_t N> 
    T* end(T (&array)[N])
    {
        return array + N;
        // or if you want to be cute
        // return 1[&array];
    }
}
```

When the bound in an array reference is a non-type template parameter, it is deducible.  Use this to your advantage when writing functions that accept arrays.

(The compiler actually has the `array + N` calculation for the end built-in for arrays, it doesn't use `std::end()` for that.  But there would be no difference after inlining anyway, and it's useful to see how you can play the same trick the compiler does.)

Comment: That's ... not like the standard does it.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Which part, the initialization of `__end`, or the definition of `end()` ?

Comment: @Deduplicator: According to 24.7, this is the correct definition of `std::end()`, if you add `constexpr` and `noexcept` modifiers.

Comment: @BenVoigt 24.7 seems to be post-C++11. I can't find it in the C++11 standard.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Ahh, found what you meant.  There's no difference after inlining, anyway.  And it *does* use a termination condition, not a counter.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It's that number in both n3485 and the current version.  Otherwise use the section name `[iterator.range]` or the nifty "Index of library names" to find the definition.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The important part is that it does not use `end()` or `begin()` for arrays *at all*.

Comment: OK, 24.6.5 in C++11. The `constexpr` and `noexcept` are post C++11 additions, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm a novice to C++. I understand what is going on for the most part but I'm nit sure about N. How is it calculated? It seems like it would have to be the size of the array / the size of the element - 1 if the goal is to find the end of the array. Is that what is occurring?

Comment: @Bren: `N` is the size in the array type (The parameter is of type `T(&)[N]` which means a reference to `T[N]`, an array of `N` elements of type `T`).  Both `T` and `N` are deduced by template matching when the compiler finds the overload candidate set.  The resulting point is `array + N`, which is *after* the last element.  As mentioned in my note, though, the compiler skips all this for arrays and gets to the end result much faster by simply looking up the array size for the variable your provided (size is stored in its internal data and used for `sizeof` as well).

Comment: @Bren: Notice because the loop looks like `for( ; it != __end; ++it )` that the last item processed is `*(__end-1)`.  That's why the one-past-the-end pointer is used.

Comment: I guess I need to learn more about template matching but I'm going to go ahead and accept the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this works is that the `for` loop effectively<sup>1</sup> uses `std::begin` and `std::end`. Those, in turn, work, because they provide overloads specifically for built-in arrays, something like this:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
T *begin(T (&array)[N]) {
    return array;
}

template <class T, size_t N>
T *end(T (&array)[N]) {
    return array+N;
}
```

Although it (apparently) hadn't been realized before the original (1998) C++ standard was published, this technique doesn't require any language features beyond those available in C++98. C++11 codified the technique and puts it to use.

Since, in this case, the parameter is specified as a reference to an array, type deduction will only succeed when the parameter really is an array. In the case of `std::begin`, there are also versions that support other parameter types and use (for example) the `begin()` and `end()` members of collections, if that type is matched.

---

<sub>1. "Effectively" in this case meaning there are some circumstances in which a range-based for loop uses `begin` and `end`, and others in which they're not. If you're into technicalities, they're not used for arrays, but a similar computation is done directly. Likewise, for container types that have `begin` and `end` members, those are used directly. If neither of those is true, then `begin(range)` and `end(range)` are used, which can use either `std::begin`/`std::end`, or a `begin(x)`/`end(x)` pair found by argument dependent lookup.</sub>

Comment: Use of member `begin()` and `end()` for containers is done for ranged-for loops automatically, without relying on `std::begin()` and `std::end()` overloads.  See 6.5.4 in the Standard.

Comment: I'm a novice to C++. I understand what is going on for the most part but I'm nit sure about N. How is it calculated? It seems like it would have to be the size of the array / the size of the element - 1 if the goal is to find the end of the array. Is that what is occurring? –

Comment: Yes, the compiler knows the declared type of the array (e.g., knows that `int a[2];` is an array of `int`s).

Answer (score 4):

The compiler knows the number of elements of the array due to the array definition. So it uses expressions `myarray` and `myarray + 3` to traverse the array.

In fact the loop looks the following way

```
for ( auto first = myarray, last = myarray + 3; first != last; ++first )
{
   auto elem = *first;
   cout << elem << '\n';
}
```

Take into account that the range-based for statement **use neither std::begin() nor std::end() for arrays** as others wrote here.:)

According to the C++ Standard

> — if **_RangeT is an array type**, begin-expr and end-expr are
>   **__range** and **__range + __bound**, respectively, where __bound is the array bound. If _RangeT is an array of unknown size or an array of
>   incomplete type, the program is ill-formed;

Comment: +1 for the last point. It wouldn't make much sense to use `std::begin` and `std::end` for an array in C++11. In C++14 they return `constexpr` so it could make sense (but seems unnecessary.)

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Neither std::begin nor std:;end are used in the range based for statement with arrays.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler knows the actual type of the array and uses a standard iterator-based loop with `array` (equivalent to `array + 0`) and `array + length` (equivalent to `*(&array + 1)`) as start respective end of the range.

For a non-array, it first looks for `begin` and `end` in the given range, then finally uses ADL to find free functions.

All but using ADL to find free functions will be done equally by `std::begin` and `std::end`, thus if you use `using std::begin;` and `using std::end;` in your code, unqualified name-lookup will mimic the rules of the ranged-for-loop.

The proper section from C++1y:

> #### 6.5.4 The range-based for statement [stmt.ranged]
>
> 1 For a range-based `for` statement of the form
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement
> ```
>
> let `range-init` be equivalent to the `expression` surrounded by parentheses<sub>90</sub> `( expression )` and for a range-based for statement of the form
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : braced-init-list ) statement
> ```
>
> let `range-init` be equivalent to the `braced-init-list`. In each case, a range-based `for` statement is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     auto && __range = range-init;
>     for ( auto __begin = begin-expr, __end = end-expr;
>               __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
>         for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>         statement
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> where `__range`, `__begin`, and `__end` are variables defined for exposition only, and `_RangeT` is the type of the expression, and `begin-expr` and `end-expr` are determined as follows:
>
> - if `_RangeT` is an array type, `begin-expr` and `end-expr` are `__range` and `__range + __bound`, respectively, where `__bound` is the array bound. If `_RangeT` is an array of unknown size or an array of incomplete type, the program is ill-formed;
> - if `_RangeT` is a class type, the unqualified-ids `begin` and `end` are looked up in the scope of class `_RangeT` as if by class member access lookup (3.4.5), and if either (or both) finds at least one declaration, `beginexpr` and `end-expr` are `__range.begin()` and `__range.end()`, respectively;
> - otherwise, `begin-expr` and `end-expr` are `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, respectively, where `begin` and `end` are looked up in the associated namespaces (3.4.2). *[ Note: Ordinary unqualified lookup (3.4.1) is not performed. —end note ]*
>
> 2 In the *decl-specifier-seq* of a *for-range-declaration*, each *decl-specifier* shall be either a *type-specifier* or *constexpr*.